# Does RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken exist in SOAP API?

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I'm trying to make use of the RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken via the SOAP API. My solution currently uses Embedded Sending thanks to the RequestSenderToken method, but RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken does not seem to exist within my instance of DSAPIService. Has this method been deprecated? I am currently exclusively using the SOAP API but I would consider using REST for this one purpose if similar functionality exists.

```
public class ServiceWrapper : DSAPIService
{
//override of GetWebRequest here
}

public class DocuSignJob
{
    public string GetSenderToken(string envelopeID, string accountid)
    {
        string sendurl, historyurl;
        using (ServiceWrapper client = new ServiceWrapper())
        {
            sendurl = client.RequestSenderToken(_envelopeID, accounted, "http://www.google.com");  //works
            historyurl = client.RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken(envelopeid, "http://www.google.com"); //ServiceWrapper does not contain a definition for 'RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why (perhaps legacy, perhaps bug, perhaps something else) but the `RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken` SOAP call seems to exist in the `api.asmx` service but not the `dsapi.asmx` service:

https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx

Try hitting that instead and it should work.

https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?op=RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken

---

Update:

After reading some more documentation it looks like besides one or two method differences that the main difference between api and dsapi services is how you authenticate your calls.  The API service requires a WS-Security UsernameToken, DSAPI requires an HTTP auth header.

See [page 19 of SOAP API guide](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf#page=19) for more info.

Comment: It looks like that will work though I had to resolve many ambiguity errors in my project since it now contains both the dsapi.asmx and api.asmx service references.

Comment: However I'm now getting the "Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message" error from the RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken call. Is there an example somewhere of how I should be creating the HTTP header for the api.asmx service as opposed to the dsapi.asmx service? Does it still involve overriding GetWebRequest()?

Comment: I nearly have things working now but often when I display the url returned by RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken I get a page that simply says "Access denied". This always happens when the envelope is in Draft and about half the time when it is In Process/Out for Signature. I do not believe it is a problem with credentials/how I am accessing the API since in the same session I can upload another envelope and RequestEnvelopeHistoryToken will work fine. Any ideas about what I can look into?